How do you call a function passing in a lambda expression?
If I had something like:
public void add(func<string, string> 
val)
{
     textval = val; // val should be hello
}

And I want to call this function
add((val) => "hello")


public void Add(Func<string, string> val)
{
    var textval = val(""); // textval should be hello
}


Several problems here:

The usual naming conventions for C# state that method names should use PascalCase, i.e., start with an upper-case letter. Add in this case.
The C# language is case sensitive. There is no func delegate, but several Func<...> delegates with a different number of parameters. Therefore, write Func<string, string>.
You are assigning the result of the call to a local variable, but you never declared this variable. Variable declarations are introduced by a type name or var telling the compiler to infer the type.

public void Add(Func<string, string> val)
{
    string textval = val(null);
}

Note that you are not using the input parameter to the delegate val. Therefore, you could declare the parameter as Func<string> with a return type of string, but no input parameter.
public void Add(Func<string> val)
{
    string textval = val();
}

Naming: naming is difficult, but it is worth spending some time on it to make the code more readable. Since the usage of this method is unknown, it is difficult to give you a better advice, but I would go with something like this:
public void Add(Func<string> getValue)
{
    string text = getValue();
}

The name getValue uses a verb and a noun. The verb get indicates that we are doing something and especially getting something, in contrast to, e.g., a simple value parameter which could be string value. The noun indicates what we are getting. It could be more specific if we knew what the string represents. Examples: getMessage, getErrorMessage, getUserName, etc.

Suppose you want to bring an object I into the state I' by means of a transformation T. The transformation function f should also be variable.
T (I, f) => I'
The transformation of a string could serve as an example by appending another string to any string I. So:
T ("Hello ‘, f) => ’Hello World”
where the transformation function is declared as f(s) => s +“World”.
In C#, this can be formulated very simply using generics:
T Transform <T> (T i, Func<T,T> f) => f (i);

and the call of the transformation:
var i = Transform(“Hello ", s => string.Concat(s, "World”));

(I realize that this is quite academic and the example is actually too cumbersome. But the principle should be shown. This is a very simple version of a monad in C#).
